# Add elements with user Input in a null ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, null, addition

I explain, I am trying to make the user enter five elements in a list with a fixed size of five elements; for this I have initialized these elements in null. My problem is that I don't know exactly how to do it for this particular case. I've tried this, but it's clearly not the right solution.

I made this code into two different empty constructor methods, to be used in a main class with the familiar main method. But this class is the one I have the most trouble with.

Btw! I want the user to add the elements, not me.

````java
package HashArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class arrayListNull {
    public static void arrayList() {
         ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         list.add(null);
         list.add(null);
         list.add(null);
         list.add(null);
         list.add(null);  
    }
    public static void inputUser() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
            arrayList.list.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(arrayList.list);
        scanner.close();
    }
}```
````

Comment: You have no `main` method.  Can you show it to us?

Comment: There is no such thing as a null arraylist. Your method is `void`, that means it doesn't return anything. The nothing it returns can't be accessed with the syntax you seem to want. Additionally, you aren't actually calling the method.

Comment: @markspace I would show it to you, the reason it doesn't contain it here is because this is a class that I will use in a main class that contains a menu. That's why I used void.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So what should I use if I want to use this class in a main class?

Comment: What is the point of `arrayListNull` if all of your methods are static?  Might as well just have made these static methods in the same class that contains `main()`.  WHY are you using this class? Is there some kind of requirement you're trying to meet here?

Comment: *So what should I use if I want to use this class in a main class?* Obviously you don't. Because none of this is legal syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a public method named `arrayList` that returns nothing (void). That method (a) instantiates an `ArrayList` object, (b) populates the list with null references, which is redundant as nulls are the default, and (c) discards that `ArrayList` object by the end of the method. Poof, gone.

So your other method `inputUser` refers to a variable named `arrayList` which never existed.

Your code has other problems. You are not following Java naming conventions: classes start with uppercase, methods and variables lowercase. You are relying too much on `static`, likely a sign that you are not learning object-oriented concepts. And you seem to be coding blindly, without thinking it through, and without working with other example code. I suggest you review your textbook and the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) provided by Oracle free-of-cost.

By the way, use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close resources such as `Scanner` objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that it is an activity of the training that you are doing and you are stuck. You can try this:

```
public static void inputUser() {
    List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    int allowInputs = 5;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < allowInputs; i++) {
        arrayList.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    scanner.close();

    System.out.println("Your specified elements:");
    arrayList.forEach(System.out::println);
}

// RUN
public static void main(String[] args) {
    inputUser();
}
```

good coding! ¯_(ツ)_/¯